# Return a resolved $Resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm kind of new to AngularJS and promises in JavaScript.
I've got a .config which uses a provider to create menus in the application that I'm working on.

This provider has an enabled property, in this enabled property I want to check if a user is an admin of an organization. This menu item should only be shown if the user is an admin.

Some code:

```
PageMenuProvider
    .page('organization', 'dashboard', {
      state: 'organization.dashboard',
      label: 'SW.ORGANIZATION.DASHBOARD.LABEL',
      weight: -60,
      enabled: ['$stateParams', '$rootScope', 'Organization', function ($stateParams, $rootScope, Organization) {
        return Organization.get({ slug: $stateParams.slug }).$promise
          .then(function (organization) {
            return organization.user_role === 'management' || $rootScope.isAdmin
          })
      }]
    })
```

The problem is that I get a $promise as return value, and not the desired boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of promises and asynchronous programming!

Yes - you will have a promise returned since your first return statement is on `Organization.get`

However when this promise resolves you will get the Boolean you expected.

I'm second guessing you a bit - but if you're trying to block a page from loading until a promise has completed you should look at the resolve functionality in controllers.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: The problem is that you don't have access to $scope in the provider. And I certainly don't want to do this on $rootScope.

Comment: You probably want to store isAdmin on some concept of a user entity rather than the $rootScope. The key to get this to work is where `enabled` gets processed. As I say that method will return a promise - within their you need to resolve and process the response.